# Interpret keyboard shortcut in VMWare, not in Windows

Tags: vmware, hotkeys

I have a VMWare setup with Windows 10 as host, and Archlinux as guest. In my VM, I use keyboard shortcuts all the time, specifically `Win+l`. Whenever I do this, however, Windows logs me out, since this appears to be the key combination for, well, logging out.

I understand that this cannot be changed in Windows. However, can I catch the keys somehow and tell Windows to send it to the VMWare guest, rather than interpreting it itself? My understand here is very rudimentary, so I am not sure if I even pose the question well. All I want to do is using `Win+l` without being logged out in Windows.

I can change the key combination in Archlinux, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure VMware Tools have been installed in the Guest Machine and then keep the Mouse in the machine you are using: Host or Guest.

If your Mouse is active in the Host, the keyboard will only send signals to the Host.

If your Mouse is active in the Guest, the keyboard will only send signals to the Guest.

That is the way VMware works and you need to be certain what machine is "active" as that is where keystrokes will go. It is the Mouse that controls focus; Ctrl-Alt to leave a machine to go to Host; but not the general keyboard.  (See VMware Preferences for available Hot Keys).

Posted from my Kali Virtual Machine in VMware Workstation V16.

**NOTE:**  In VMware 16, WIN+L apparently supersedes VMware control.

In my Kali Guest, WIN+L logs me out of Kali and Windows 10 both.

WIN+R and other WIN combinations do not action Windows from the Guest.

So you will have to change the Linux WIN+L shortcut. That is the only way this work for you.

Comment: Thanks. It's not what I observe, though. I am using the guest system only, and as soon as I hit `Win+l`, I am logged out from Windows. I try reinstalling VMWare Tools.

Comment: Good idea. VMware tools are very important to control the mouse and machine focus. This trips me up from time to time.

Comment: I amended my Answer. WIN+ most things do not affect the other system. But WIN+L is apparently grabbed by Windows (assuming Windows 10 to be the Host). I tried WIN+L from Kali and was logged out of Kali and Windows both (but not the other machines also running) . So you will have to change your ArchLinux guest Shortcut combination. That is the only way this will work for you.

Comment: I see. Thanks for checking. Bummer.

Comment: Yes, bummer  - I understand. But that is how this works. I was happy to work with you on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to this for Windows 7 up to 11.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `regedit`
2. Go to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\`
3. Check if a key (looks similiar to a directory) named `System` exists:  If NO (if yes skip this step):

- In the left column right click on the `Policies` key and choose `New` > `Key` to create a new key with the name: `System`

4. Right-click the `System` key and choose `New` >`DWORD (32-bit)` and give the value the name: `DisableLockWorkstation`
5. Double-click the new `DisableLockWorkstation` value to open its properties window. Change the value from `0` to `1` in the `Value data` box to enable the new key, which in turn disables the lock
6. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, you should not get locked out anymore